# Wait until a Curl command ends

Tags: php, shell, curl

I have this shell script for running two php scripts continuously.

```
while [ true ]
do
    curl -s 'example.com/first.php' > /dev/null
    curl -s 'example.com/second.php' > /dev/null
    sleep 30;
done
```

But some times I think it doesn't work fine, for example it runs `first.php` two times at the same time.
Does `curl` command run the `second.php` before end of `first.php` process? How can I solve that?
I also didn't use `exit` in my `first.php` & `second.php`